# Groovy script talk with Grails Application (server) and Tally server

Tags: grails, groovy, java-7

Need help For following points:

1. Groovy script talk with Grails application read data as JSON.
2. Groovy script talk with tally server read file in xml format.

Grails application server  file fromat as `json ->   Groovy script -> Tally server` only xml files

Answer (score 1):

thake a look at http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_groovy/ - you'll find the cookbook recipes you need...